pass Custom Token to backend
WSo2 API-Manager .
I'm working with APIs on the backend:
API-1: This endpoint, located at /api/GetToken, is responsible for issuing access tokens.

API-2: It's designed for sending SMS messages and resides at /api/sendSMS. However, it requires a valid token obtained from API-1 to function properly.

API-3: need token  from api-1 , etc ..
So, the challenge is to seamlessly pass the token retrieved from /api/GetToken to the endpoint /api/sendSMS for successful SMS delivery using WSo2 APIM
I tried to add custom policies "sequence " in header request

This use case is pretty much similar to the usual API secured by OAuth2 in API Manager. What you have is a different token endpoint instead of the API Manager key manager token endpoint. So, you can do the following things to achieve your use case:

Create a Managed API for the /api/GetToken API and secure the API the way you want.
Create separate Managed APIs for the other APIs /api/sendSMS, etc., and you can disable security for these APIs since you already secured these APIs. (Or you can add another security layer by enabling security, and it is up to you.)

The special point here is that since other APIs have authentication mechanisms on the backend side, you need to pass some authorization header to the backend for validation. Usually, the API Manager gateway drops the Authorization header. In order to achieve your use case, you need to attach a mediation policy to the other APIs.
In this example, from the client side, you need to send 2 headers called Authorization and Custom.
In your API request, you pass the token that is generated in the Authorization header (if you add security for your APIs in the API Manager side as well), and the backend token you got from your /api/GetToken API in a Custom header. The mediation extension you write extracts the value of the Custom header and sets it as the Authorization header before sending it to the backend.
Here's a summary:
Client (headers: Authorization, Custom)→ Gateway (drop: Authorization, convert: Custom->Authorization) → Backend
To add the mediation sequence to your APIs do the followings,

Add the following sequence content to a file and save it as tokenExchange.xml.
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TokenExchange">
 <property name="Custom" expression="get-property('transport', 'Custom')"/>
 <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Custom')" scope="transport"/>
 <property name="Custom" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
</sequence>


Navigate to the API Configurations → Policies tab. Create a new policy with the information given in the table below by following the instructions in Create a Policy.
Name:   Custom Authorization Token 
Version:    1.0 
Applicable Flows:   Request 
Supported API Types:    HTTP 
Policy File:    tokenExchange.xml file you created 
Policy Attributes:  N/A N/A 

Then attach the created custom policy to the API's particular resource request flow by dragging and dropping it, and then save the API.


For every APIs, make sure to navigate to the Deployments tab and click on Deploy New Revision button. Also, if the API is not in PUBLISHED state, navigate to the Lifecycle tab and publish your API.
Then, those APIs will be available in the developer portal of the API Manager. Now, you can develop an application in any language that calls the token endpoint, retrieves the token, and invokes the other APIs according to your use cases.
